# Dream position I cannot afford

Tags: salary, canada

I am a recent Law school graduate who secured an articling position in the Greater Toronto Area. After deductions and allowances, I will be earning $1840 net. I have to have a working vehicle to be able to drive to different court locations, some of which will be a two hours' drive one-way.

The employer was originally only going to hire one person, but decided to hire two people, instead. I considered it a fourth year of education and secured a $20,000 line of credit. With this amount, I would have been barely able to make ends meet. Today I found out I have to pay nearly $5000 for licensing fees.

What should I do? I nearly had to beg my financial institution to lend me the amount.

Comment: How it's a "dream" job if you have to pay to do it?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY he is being paid. Just not enough for the GTA on that salary.

Comment: Is there no public transportation?

Comment: If you cannot "afford" your dream job, it's not a job. The whole point of a job is to keep you afloat. If it does not pay you enough to actually do it, it's a hobby. So yeah, I guess you need a real job and it might not be your dream job. I guess we all have a dream job that would not pay our bills.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY It is with a firm in the field of law in which I want to practice, and it has a good reputation.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Exactly.

Comment: @guest Yes, there is public transportation, but I need to have a reliable vehicle as part of the position.

Comment: @nvoigt It is an articling position, which is the equivalent of an apprenticeship. Articling students are not protected under the Employment Standards legislation.

Comment: @user24361 You are paying with your time and effort. The only point of doing it is to have enough to do it. If new tires, dentist, cinema ticket pop out you're screwed. You have minus amount of money. What you are describing is like "apprenticeship" you pay with your time, they give you just enough for you to not die of hunger and you get experience. Nothing more. If that is your dream...

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Yes, it is basically like an apprenticeship. It is an articling position, which is the equivalent of a legal apprenticeship. And yes, I am pretty much screwed if any expenses come up.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Common for law jobs - its hard for poor people to - this may or may not be design

Answer (score 10):

1. **Apply for support.** On that salary, you are low income and like it probably says on your diploma, are entitled to all the rights, privileges, and realities of that. I assume you have a utility bill, so start by applying to the [Electricity Support Program.](https://ontarioelectricitysupport.ca/) I paid all of $20 in utilities during my time studying at Queen's University.  It was worth about $700 a year for me. Depending on where exactly you live in the GTA, other support may be available.
2. **Look at expensing that vehicle and its costs.** Expenses you are required to incur for your job are tax deductible. In this case, that vehicle, its gas, its insurance, etc. all should qualify. [See more here.](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/benefits-allowances/automobile/automobile-motor-vehicle-allowances/employees-allowable-employment-expenses.html)
3. **Change the deductions.** You should pay very little tax next year at that income once you factor in things like your tuition credit and tax deductions. As a result, you can use [this form](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/payroll/set-up-new-employee/filing-form-td1.html) to adjust how much tax is being withheld. It means a much smaller tax refund at the end of the year, but gives you more to live on now.
4. **Have you filed your taxes this year?**  If you worked last summer, you should be getting something sizable back.
5. **You might get an even larger tax return next year.** There are even more tax credits for people who are working but low income such as [this.](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/child-family-benefits/witb-eligibility.html) If there is some way to rearrange your expenses to wait for that, you might consider next year's tax return as well. That tax credit is refundable, so it wouldn't be impacted by reducing your deductions.
6. **Could you rent a car instead?** Car rental is absurdly cheap right now for obvious reasons to the point where many gig economy drivers are renting rather than using their own vehicles.
7. **Run through your expenses for possible savings.** If you have student loans, have you factored in your interest relief due to COVID? Are you using any service from Telus, Rogers, or Bell? Bell would have been an extra $40 a month when I lived in Kingston. They are almost certainly fleecing you. Have you looked at dividend credit cards? 1% back is still an extra $100 or so a year on your non-rent expenses.
8. **Look at the gig economy market.** Lots of DoorDash and Instacart work available at the moment.
9. **Look at specific financial aid.** I assume the $5000 is in part your articling fee. [There are dedicated loans available for that.](https://lso.ca/becoming-licensed/lawyer-licensing-process/candidate-supports/financial-assistance)

Comment: This. If it's a dream job, you gotta do whatever you can to secure it.

Comment: @Matthewgaiser Thank you for your detailed response. I have filed my taxes for last year and did received around $1400, which I already used toward this vehicle. Do you have any recommendations on car rental agencies? As far as the gig economy market, I do not know whether I would be able to as I need to be available all the time for this position. As far as that link for the financial aid, I can pay the $5000 over the ten months, but I still have to pay it.

Comment: @user24361 if you already have the car, forget the rental idea as you won't be able to sell that vehicle right now. Can you still tap Government of Canada student loan money?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I do not believe I can as I graduated.

Comment: @user24361 what kind of loan are you getting? As they have specific loans for law students who are articling at banks like CIBC.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I have a professional student line of credit at prime rate. During my articling period, I only have to pay interest only payments, which are approximately $200.

Comment: @user24361 perhaps try a different bank for another one?

Answer (score 3):

Have you enquired if you can expense the travel between locations or if there is some travel allowance available? Seems reasonable to me that travel required of you during the course of your daily workload should not leave you out of pocket.

Alternatively, if you wouldn't need the car for anything else, can you expense cab rides instead? This would cut out the cost of insurance, tax, parking, maintenance and any loan facility availed of to buy the car. Maybe that's not an option for a 2 hour each-way spin.

Comment: Yes, I am reimbursed $100 per month for fuel. And yes, I would agree. Cab rides would be too expensive, I think. Most often the drive would be 35 minutes each-way going to Toronto.

Comment: Do you know if $100 a month is enough to cover your costs. Over the course of a month, track how much fuel you use (the total value - not your net spend), the total distance travelled in the month and the distance travelled on work related matters (excluding your commute). If work accounts for 25% of your travel then $100 should cover 25% of your spend on fuel. In fact, I'd argue that since the wear and tear will be greater and higher mileage will affect resale values, your allowance should be slightly in excess of that. Maybe a chat with the finance dept is in order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your dreams.

You are broke (not uncommon for most terminal degree students) and they are offering pay that is on par with working at a fast food restaurant.  You would be better off working at a more menial job as the car and travel requirements would not be there, and there would be a lot less licensing fees.  The fees probably do not end with the 5K they are talking about.

What will change if you do take this job?  How can you afford to pay anything back?  Even if you convince a bank to loan you the money, where will the money come from to pay off this debt?  Consider that poor credit risk, and you are a poor credit risk because of your income, pay much higher interest rates.

The only way that you can make this work is if there is a much higher payout in a few years, and in the short term you can work a second and possibly a third job until that time.

Comment: Actually, I would make more working at a fast food restaurant. Based on a 40 hour week, I would earn $2240 gross, and I will be working for far more than 40 hours each week with this position (more like a minimum of 60 hours).  What will change if I do take this job? Well, I don't know how familiar with the legal profession, but after I have done this year, I will be able to practice law on my own. As far as a second and third job, I do not see my employer allowing me to do that...

Comment: So you have no choice.  You need a different job.  Where will you get the money to open your own practice?